# How to remove both windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04 and also delete all files from hard disk?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, dualboot

In my laptop ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10 is installed. Now i want to remove both the OS and also delete all file, basically like factory reset. What is the easiest way to do this?
N.B I don't need the original OS.

Comment: Assuming Factory Reset is Windows, just use the option to delete ALL partitions.  Then a modern OS will create the needed 3 partitions.

Comment: Are you saying that from `diskmgmt` i have to delete all partitions? what happens then, the computer turns off automatically? I am afraid there might be some side effect like boot loading, should i be concerned about this?

Comment: That is what I would do if doing a fresh install

Comment: @John i am concerned about the ubuntu, ubuntu brings so many weird side effects specially when i am not expert

Comment: Make and model of laptop???